# root.destroy() from an external module?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is there any way that I can somehow destroy root upon clicking a logout button in a module outside of the file where root is being created?  For example,

```
def logout(self):
    self.destroy()
    root.destroy()
```

is contained in a file called `Menu.py`.

```
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI")
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300, 180))
lf = LoginFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

is contained in a file called `Client.py`.

I get the traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Pat\Documents\GitHub\DunderMifflinSales\Menu.py", line 68, in logout
    root.destroy()
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

I'd like to completely destroy all tkinter instances using the logout function.  If I exclude `root.destroy()` in logout, only the menu half of the GUI is removed.

I've attached all my code for reference:

Client.py:

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
from tkinter import ttk
import Menu

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

class LoginFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_2 = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command = self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()

    def _login_btn_clicked(self):

        username = self.entry_1.get()
        clientSocket.sendto(username.encode('UTF-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

        password = self.entry_2.get()
        clientSocket.sendto(password.encode('UTF-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

        message, address = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        message = message.decode('UTF-8')

        if message == "200 OK":
            mf = Menu.MenuFrame(root)
            mf.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        else:
            tm.showinfo(message, "Login error")

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI")
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(300, 180))
lf = LoginFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Menu.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import socket

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

class MenuFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        message = "GET name, sales"
        clientSocket.sendto(message.encode('UTF-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

        name, address = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        name = name.decode('UTF-8')

        # sales2 is the number of sales coming from the server
        sales2, address = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        sales2 = sales2.decode('UTF-8')

        # sales is the variable that will show up in the gui
        self.sales = StringVar()
        # moreSales is the user input
        self.moreSales = StringVar()
        self.sales.set(sales2)

        mainframe = ttk.Frame(self, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, W, E, S))
        mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        welcome = "Welcome, " + name

        sales_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 7, textvariable = self.moreSales)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = welcome).grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = W)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Current Sales:").grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
        ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = self.sales).grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = (E))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "sales").grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = W)

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Add Sales").grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = W)
        sales_entry.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = (W, E))
        ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Add", command = self.add).grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = W)

        ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Log Out", command = self.logout).grid(column = 2, row = 4, sticky = W)

    def add(self):

        try:
            value1 = int(self.sales.get())
            value2 = int(self.moreSales.get())
            self.sales.set(value1 + value2)


        except ValueError:
            pass

    def logout(self):

        message = self.sales.get()
        clientSocket.sendto(message.encode('UTF-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

        self.destroy()
        root.destroy()
```

Comment: Your example shows logins and sockets and stuff that isn't related to the question but makes the example impossible for us to run. A small example focusing on your problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do what you want is to make the function `logout` in `Menu.py` access the root object. You can do it in at least a few ways (it depends on the structure of your application). Here's an example.

`a.py` (your `Menu.py`)

```
root = None

def logout():
    print(root)
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()
```

`b.py` (your `Client.py`)

```
import a
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
a.root = root # Setting the global variable of the module a to this root

close = tk.Button(root, command=a.logout, text="Close")
close.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked with some tinkering.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Windows have references to their parent. Use the widget's [`winfo_toplevel` method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_toplevel-method) to get it.

Comment: There's a method that instantly gets you to the toplevel window, which is either the root window or a Toplevel: `widget.winfo_toplevel()`

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to use the root window from `Menu.py` within `Client.py`, but you haven't imported it. Try this instead of `root.destroy()`:

`Menu.root.destroy()`

Comment: `Menu` is `Menu.py`. Look at the imports for `Client.py`.

Comment: I was trying to use the root window from `Client.py` from within `Menu.py`, which I did import

Comment: The troublesome call is in `Menu.py` not `Client.py`.